# How to ignore a soft delete in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to run this query

```
$user= User::where('name', $label)->where('group', $set)->whereNull('deleted_at')->first();
dd($user);
```

but I keep getting a null

Comment: you don't need ->whereNull('deleted_at'), softdeleted items are excluded from your query automatically.

Comment: I might be confused what your actual question is... Do you have a soft-deleted record that you're trying to query and return? Or are you trying to query your database without returning the soft-deleted records? Since `dd($user);` is `null`, I think it's the first, but the query you have is backwards from how that would work (`whereNotNull('deleted_at')`, or `withTrashed()` is how you'd query for a soft-deleted record)

Comment: @TimLewis - I'm trying to query the database and leave the soft deleted item alone

Comment: Then you don't need `whereNull('deleted_at')`; if your `User` model has `use SoftDeletes;`, that clause is added automatically. If you want to query for `$label` and `$set`, and you want to include any soft-deleted records that match those columns, then include `->withTrashed()`. Please try to provide more detail when asking a question; this was far too vague on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 8):

To ignore Soft Deletes, use the `withTrashed()` method:

```
$user = User::where('name', $label)->where('group', $set)->withTrashed()->first();
```

This removes the default scope for the `deleted_at` column as it is applied when `use SoftDeletes;` is included for your model.

See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models for full details.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check that your query will actually return a result:

```
User::where('name', $label)->where('group', $set)->whereNull('deleted_at')->first();
```

Are your `where` queries going to return a user? Are `$set` and `$label` returning values you expect?

Try removing your where clauses one by one and then adding them back in to figure out which may be incorrect.

---

As mentioned in previous answers, the `SoftDeletes` trait will add the `whereNull('deleted_at')` clause, so you can ommit that from your query.